# How to programatically publish an HTML file at a Sharepoint site

Tags: html, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm pretty new to SharePoint and I need to publish HTML files (they are generated reports) in an existing SharePoint site. I've been told that you can only use the SharePoint Api if the application runs on the same server (not the case here) so what I need to do is to use the SharePoint web services.

Is that right? In that case, what should I check for this simple task (create a list at a known location and publish html file on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-through-the-built-in-web-services http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787610/how-do-you-copy-a-file-into-sharepoint-using-a-webservice

Comment: Mmmm, those looks like copying just a file. I want to copy the HTML file and update the list that shows the available pages. Not sure if they are the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes  both the questions refer to the same thing create a page library and upload your html file as suggested in below link

[Que1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-through-the-built-in-web-services)

[Que2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787610/how-do-you-copy-a-file-into-sharepoint-using-a-webservice)