# How to programatically create a folder at a Sharepoint site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

this question is related with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379139/how-to-programatically-publish-an-html-file-at-a-sharepoint-site). How can I create a folder to put the files I upload inside them without using the SharePoint API (I'm executing the application on another host)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
     SPSite _MySite = new SPSite("http://adfsaccount:2222/");
                SPWeb _MyWeb = _MySite.OpenWeb();

                SPDocumentLibrary _MyDocLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary) _MyWeb.Lists["My Documents"];
                SPFolderCollection _MyFolders = _MyWeb.Folders;
                _MyFolders.Add("http://adfsaccount:2222/My%20Documents/" + txtUpload.Text + "/");
                _MyDocLibrary.Update();
_MyWeb.Dispose();
_MySite .Dispose();
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I cannot use SharePoint API because I'm at other host.

Comment: DWorkSpace is webservice instance reference name.

DWorkSpace.Dws dwspace = new DWorkSpace.Dws();
dwspace.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
dwspace.Url = "{your_site}/_vti_bin/DWS.asmx";
dwspace.CreateFolder("Shared Documents/DemoFolder");

Answer (score 0):

I created console application to create folders. I need to give seperate permissions for each and every folder because those are all state folders. So you can look at the breakroleinheritence property also.