# Uploading a file to SharePoint copyintoitems throws error

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload

I am uploading files to SharePoint using the API `Copy.CopyIntoItems`.  The upload works when the destination url is given as "http://sharepointserver/sitename".  However, when the url is given with the domain name, like 
"http://sharepointserver.domain/sitename", then the `CopyIntoItems` API call fails, and the error returned is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Any idea on why there is a strange behavior when the url changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the url with the domain name, like "http://sharepointserver.domain/sitename" for Copying item

Answer (score 0):

The following answer on SO links to a thread on MSDN, which explains in detail why this behaviour occurs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692212/274354

Link to the MSDN thread:

[CopyIntoItems errors when using destination URI with FQDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/833e38a8-f13c-490d-8ba7-b889b6b25e38/copyintoitems-errors-when-using-destination-uri-with-fqdn?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)